# BC30311 Value of type 'Guna2TextBox' cannot be converted to 'TextBox'

Tags: vb.net

how can i fix it. I try it with gunaUicheckbox to checkbox it can work. But now i trying gunaTextBox to textbox it will show error. i store it with array

`Dim test As TextBox()
test = New TextBox() {txtAmatriciana, txtAmericano, txtApplePie, txtCafeLate, txtCappucino, txtCaramelMacciato, txtCheeseCake, txtChickenBBQParmSub, txtChickenLinguini}`

Comment: As Guna2TextBox is a custom UI framework, that's dependent on their implementation. It most likely inherits from `TextBoxBase` and not `TextBox` so it can't be converted to `TextBox`. Why not simply use a `Guna2TextBox` array? Seeing as that's you object type.

Comment: Oic . So it mean the `Guna2TextBox` cant to convert to `TextBox` Right , so how can i store the `Guna2TextBox`  value to array. Like `Guna2TextBox1` value is 2 then i want to store the value 2 to array how can i do it???

Comment: Change Dim test As TextBox() to this Dim test As Guna2TextBox()

Comment: thx for helping problems solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

`Imports Guna.UI2.WinForms`

And use Guna2Textbox() instead of Textbox()